# Is it fine to omit "application server"(e.g. Gunicorn) part when deploying a Python Backend(e.g. Flask) application on a webserver?

Tags: python, flask, apache2, wsgi

I have a Flask application running on port `5001` on my remote Ubuntu 20.04 computer. I need to make sure that it can be accessed on the internet. My organization bought the domain name `myapp.edu`.
For the web server itself they told me to use Apache2 web server. I set up my Apache2 configuration *without* any `mod_wsgi` module and by just proxying the request addressed to `https://myapp.edu:443` to `https://my-IP-address:5001` and it works for now.

But after reading up on the internet on how to set up Python backend apps, I stumbled upon WSGI servers such as **Gunicorn** that sit between the web server and the application. I see them especially when deploying Django applications in conjunction with Ngnix webserver.

I feel uneasy about how I did my setup right now, without any explicit WSGI server. I don't know if it's the correct approach.

I have tried the approach I wrote above. The main reason I am asking this is that the website is accessible on my organization's network, but not outside the network. I was wondering if not having the WSGI application server inbetween is the issue.